# How to use a separate Enum class in my form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I have a function like this

```
        public void SetOperationDropDown()
        {

        int ? cbSelectedValue = null;
        if(cmbOperations.Items.Count == 0)

            {

            //ByDefault the selected text in the cmbOperations will be -SELECT OPERATIONS-.  
            cmbOperations.SelectedItem = "-SELECT OPERATIONS-";
            //This is for adding four operations with value in operation dropdown  
            cmbOperations.Items.Insert(0, "PrimaryKeyTables");
            cmbOperations.Items.Insert(1, "NonPrimaryKeyTables");
            cmbOperations.Items.Insert(2, "ForeignKeyTables");
            cmbOperations.Items.Insert(3, "NonForeignKeyTables");
            cmbOperations.Items.Insert(4, "UPPERCASEDTables");
            cmbOperations.Items.Insert(5, "lowercasedtables");
            }
        else
            {
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty("cmbOperations.SelectedValue"))
                cbSelectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(cmbOperations.SelectedValue);
            }
        //Load the combo box cmbOperations again 
        if(cbSelectedValue != null)
            cmbOperations.SelectedValue = cbSelectedValue.ToString();
        }
```

But what I need to do if I want this function to be defined in a separate enum class and then being called.

Comment: What do you mean in a *separate enum class*?

Comment: Enum's cannot have functions / methods as its member. You may want to clarify what you are trying to achieve so that others can provide proper guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very clear what you actually want to obtain. If you want your hardcoded strings to be defined in an `enum` you could define it like this:

```
enum Tables
{
    PrimaryKeyTables,
    NonPrimaryKeyTables,
    ForeignKeyTables,
    NonForeignKeyTables,
    UPPERCASEDTables,
    lowercasedtables,
}
```

Be aware that your `string.IsNullOrEmpty("cmbOperations.SelectedValue");` always will return `false` since you are testing the specified string. You might want to test this instead:

```
cmbOperations.SelectedItem != null
```

To assign your `Tables` enum from your selection you can do like this:

```
Tables cbSelectedValue = (Tables)Enum.Parse(typeof(Tables), cmbOperations.SelectedItem.ToString());
```